# CRC check XOR Function return value is always 0

Tags: c, return, xor, crc

I am writing a code to calculate a CRC16 using 32 bit unsigned integers. When trying to print the return value out from the XOR function that performs the CRC operation it always prints 0. I've tried a variety of debug methods such as print statements, however, I can't seem to figure it out!

Here's my XOR function:

```
 uint32_t XOR(uint32_t divisor, uint32_t dividend)

{
  uint32_t divRemainder = dividend;
  uint32_t currentBit;

  for(currentBit = 32; currentBit > 0; --currentBit)
  {
    if(dividend && 0x32)
    {
      divRemainder = divRemainder ^ divisor;
    }
    divRemainder = divRemainder << 1;
  }
  return (divRemainder >> 8);
}
```

The function that calls the above method:

```
  void crcCalculation(char *text, FILE *input, char *POLYNOMIAL)
    {
      int i = strlen(text);
      uint32_t dividend = atoi(POLYNOMIAL);
      uint32_t  result;


      readInput(text, input);
      printText(text);


      printf("CRC 16 calculation progress:\n");


      if(i < 504)
      {
        for(; i!=504; i++)
        {
          text[i] = '.';
        }
      }

  result = XOR((uintptr_t)POLYNOMIAL, dividend);

      printf(" - %d", result);

}
```

The constant polynomial (I hope I calculated this correctly for CRC 16:

```
#define POLYNOMIAL A053
```

I'd appreciate a nudge in the correct direction!

Comment: Do you know the difference between logical AND and bitwise AND?

Comment: @user694733 I do not, I thought they were the same thing. I'll read up on that.

Comment: You don't make a checksum of whatever data that `POLYNOMIAL` is pointing to, but of the pointer itself. That doesn't seem very useful. You also don't calculate any checksum for the `text` string (which might not be zero-terminated). And do you really define that macro? In combination with the code you show it doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: @MartinR The macro replacement happens to be a valid symbol for a variable, and in the function shown it's a pointer so the cast works fine (unfortunately). The macro and its use doesn't make any sense though.

Comment: *"debug methods such as print statements"* That is the slow and cumbersome way to do it. Better to learn how the step through in debugger, and watch variables that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `if(dividend && 0x32)` makes no sense at all and will evaluate to `1`. This is the reason why nothing works.

Perhaps you meant `if(dividend & 32)` or similar? As in bitwise AND instead of logical AND. And hex `0x20` decimal `32` (which could make sense... probably not?) instead of hex `0x32` decimal `50` (which doesn't make any sense at all).

Overall this CRC algorithm looks very fishy. You only iterate over 31 bits, for example.

Comment: @Lundin I updated the code following your suggestions, however, it still outputs 0. Did I update it incorrectly?

Comment: @starlight I'm not really understanding the implementation, I don't follow what the 32 bit integers are supposed to do, aren't you using a 16 bit polynomial? Also in general, please don't edit questions so that they ask something completely different, when there are answers posted. If you need to ask further specific questions, post a new question.